# How to change folder's creation date to match the creation date of the .nfo file inside?

Tags: command-line, touch

I need to do it for over 600 folders with varying names and the .nfo file inside doesn't necessarily have the same name as the folder, he is just a few of them.

```
m0j0@unity ~/files/TV.TL/TEST $ ls -lr
total 28
drwxrwx--- 2 m0j0 m0j0  162 Nov 30 19:57 G.S01E07.720p.AMZN.WEB-DL
drwxrwx--- 2 m0j0 m0j0  164 Nov 30 19:57 G.S01E07.1080p.AMZN.WEB-DL
drwxrwx--- 2 m0j0 m0j0  148 Nov 30 19:57 G.S01E06.S.1080p.AMZN.WEB-DL
drwxrwx--- 3 m0j0 m0j0 4096 Nov 30 19:57 G.S01E06.HDTV
drwxrwx--- 3 m0j0 m0j0 4096 Nov 30 19:57 G.S01E06.720p.WEB
drwxrwx--- 3 m0j0 m0j0 4096 Nov 30 19:57 G.S01E06.720p.HDTV
drwxrwx--- 3 m0j0 m0j0 4096 Nov 30 19:57 G.S01E05.HDTV
drwxrwx--- 3 m0j0 m0j0 4096 Nov 30 19:57 G.S01E05.720p.WEB
drwxrwx--- 3 m0j0 m0j0 4096 Nov 30 19:57 G.S01E05.720p.HDTV
drwxrwx--- 3 m0j0 m0j0 4096 Nov 30 19:57 G.S01E05.1080p.WEB

m0j0@unity ~/files/TV.TL/TEST $ find . -iregex '.*\.\(nfo\)' -printf '%Tc %f\n'
Mon 13 Nov 2017 10:02:05 AM +08 g.s01e06.720p.hdtv.nfo
Wed 22 Nov 2017 08:17:40 AM +08 G.S01E07.1080p.AMZN.WEB-DL.nfo
Wed 22 Nov 2017 08:17:12 AM +08 G.S01E07.720p.AMZN.WEB-DL.nfo
Tue 14 Nov 2017 02:47:07 AM +08 G.S01E06.1080p.AMZN.WEB-DL.nfo
Mon 06 Nov 2017 09:58:54 AM +08 g.s01e05.1080p.web.nfo
Mon 06 Nov 2017 10:01:02 AM +08 g.s01e05.hdtv.nfo
Mon 13 Nov 2017 10:02:23 AM +08 g.s01e06.hdtv.nfo
Mon 06 Nov 2017 09:57:15 AM +08 g.s01e05.720p.web.nfo
Mon 06 Nov 2017 10:01:27 AM +08 g.s01e05.720p.hdtv.nfo
Mon 13 Nov 2017 09:57:36 AM +08 g.s01e06.720p.web.nfo
```

Comment: (1) Do you want creation date/time or modification date/time? (2) Unless the question is about long file names, the polite thing to do is to use short names in your question — ten characters should be enough. Your question has filenames up to 65 characters long. (3) Why are you using `-iregex '.*\.\(nfo\)'`? Wouldn’t `-iname '*.nfo'` do the same thing? (4) Since you used `-printf %f`, we can’t tell (3a) whether you have at most one `.nfo` file per directory, or possibly more than one, or (3b) whether the `.nfo` files are immediately *in* the top-level directories, or only somewhere under them.

Comment: (Cont’d) …  For question #1 (creation date / time vs. modification date / time), if you don’t know the difference, do the research *on your own* to figure it out.

Comment: to be quite honest the commands i was using to list the files i have got from other questions on stackexchange, im still really new to linux. and i did some reading about creating dates and modification dates and i think you are right, its not creation dates that id like to change, its modification dates. also good call about the polite file names, ill edit that part out.

Comment: i would still welcome an example of how to go about doing the same thing to the folder's creation date aswell, thanks.

Comment: See the `--reference` switch of `touch` command:

     -r, --reference=FILE
              use this file's times instead of current time

Comment: i have actually read that and have tested it, i can change the date of a directory to a file, my issue is doing this with some sort of a "for" loop which can do it for all 600 over directories

Comment: best i can tell my for command should look something like
`for i in *;do touch -r "$i/*.nfo" "$i";done`
but my * wildcard in *.nfo doesnt seem to be doing the trick

Comment: The asterisk should be outside the quotes. Use "$i/"*.nfo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to do it with the following command: 
`for i in *;do touch -r "$i/"*.nfo`